# Why does my values in a list doesn't calculate sum odd and even numbers differently and return it in a new list?

Tags: python, list

I have list named li with values [1,2,4,5] and I want to return a new list with sum of odd numbers and even numbers like new_list = [6,6] where values add as 1+5 = 6 and 2+4 = 6. But, the output that I am receiving is [1]. Below is my code.

```
class Solution(object):

    def calculate_odd_even(self, li):

        even = 0
        odd = 0

        sum_num = []

        for i in range(len(li)):
            if li[i] % 2 == 0:
                even += 1
                sum_num.append(even)
            else:
                odd += 1
                sum_num.append(odd)

            return sum_num


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Solution()
    lit = [1, 2, 4, 5]
    print(p.calculate_odd_even(lit))
```

Comment: You want to append to `sum_num` and `return` it ***after*** the loop, not at every step within the loop.

Comment: You return *inside* the for loop. You probably want to return *outside* the for loop. Dedent `return sum_num` by one indentation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code.

- you `return` too early (in the loop)
- you add +1 instead of the value
- you try to append to each loop (do it only in the end)
- the order of the odd/even values depends on the input data (first one seen of odd/even will be first)

Other "minor" issue:

- don't loop over the indices, loop over the values

```
class Solution(object):

    def calculate_odd_even(self, li):
        even = 0
        odd = 0

        sum_num = []
        for x in li:
            if x % 2 == 0:
                even += x
            else:
                odd += x
                
        sum_num.append(odd)
        sum_num.append(even)
        return sum_num


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Solution()
    lit = [1, 2, 4, 5]
    print(p.calculate_odd_even(lit))
```

More simple variant:

```
class Solution(object):

    def calculate_odd_even(self, li):
        sum_num = [0, 0]
        for x in li:
            sum_num[1-x%2] += x  # use sum_num[x%2] += x for even/odd order
        return sum_num


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Solution()
    lit = [1, 2, 4, 5]
    print(p.calculate_odd_even(lit))
```

Comment: What's the difference if I add in the loop or outside?

Comment: `return` terminates the execution of the function as soon as it's encountered. You want to `return` in the end, else you just test the first value.